# Is link posting broken if the link includes a caret?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

I think including links is broken if the valid URL includes a caret symbol `^`.  See as below this link to Wolfram Alpha for computing `2^25`:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2^25

It is a valid URL but gets truncated by the markup engine at the caret symbol.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The caret isn't a valid character in an URL, and should be escaped.

This happens automatically if you use the link toolbar button or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> like so:

[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2^25](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E25)

Comment: That's correct.  For further reading, RFC 1945, which defines the HTTP, specifies all the format of a URL and all its valid characters in sections 3.2.2 and 3.2.1 (on pages 15 and 14):  http://rfc1945.openrfc.org/